# Hazelcast split-brain

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast (3.7.4) with OpenShift.
Each application is starting a HazelcastInstance.

The network discovery is done via hazelcast-kubernetes (1.1.0).

Sometimes when I deploy the whole application, the cluster is stuck in a split-brain syndrom forever. It never fix and reconnect the whole cluster.

I have to restart pods to enable the reconstruction of a single cluster.

Can someone help me to prevent the split-brain or at least making it recover after ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **StatefulSet** instead of **Deployment** (or **ReplicationController**). Then, PODs start one by one which prevents the Split Brain issue. You can have a look at the official [OpenShift Code Sample for Hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/openshift) or specifically at the [OpenShift template for Hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/hazelcast-integration/openshift/hazelcast-cluster/hazelcast-openshift-origin/hazelcast.yaml).

What's more, try to use the latest Hazelcast version, I think it should re-form the cluster even if you use **Deployment** and the cluster starts with a Split Brain.

Comment: I agree that the cluster should re-form. I'll try to update Hazelcast but I'm afraid about springboot compatiblity and hibernate compatibility. I'll look at it thanks